# Preserve Animation Speed Setting Across Refresh

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In the Google Dev Tools "Animations" pane, there is an option (pictured below) to set the speed of animations.

That setting is reset to 100% every time I refresh the page; is there any way/setting that will preserve that 10%/25% setting across refreshes?

The reason I want this is I want to see a slowed-down version of an animation that is played after the page is reloaded.

---

[image: Animations Pane Screenshot of the setting in question]
*The setting in question*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no setting to keep the animation speed to the level you set. There might be a way to hack the internals of DevTools to preserve the setting. You can open a feature request at https://crbug.com.